# How do I check if a 2 dimensional point is inside a polygon in C#?

Tags: c#, vector, 2d, polygon, collision

I've had this problem and didn't find a proper way to check if a given X,Y point is inside an arbitrary 2 dimensional polygon.

After a couple of hours I managed to find a way which also considers points that are right on the edge of a polygon to count as a match.

Comment: Use [GraphicsPath.AddPolygon()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16k3da3w(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GraphicsPath.IsVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d20k495d(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: That does work when you're using WinForms.

Comment: ...and you are, or are **not** using WinForms?  You haven't specified your environment.  =)

Answer (score 0):

By using a custom class Vector2 with double X and double Y properties you can use the following code to check if a given "Position" is within a polygon of "Points":

```
    public bool CheckCollision( Vector2[] Points, Vector2 Position )
    {
        double MinX = Points.Min( a => a.X );
        double MinY = Points.Min( a => a.Y );
        double MaxX = Points.Max( a => a.X );
        double MaxY = Points.Max( a => a.Y );

        if( Position.X < MinX || Position.X > MaxX || Position.Y < MinY || Position.Y > MaxY )
            return false;

        int I = 0;
        int J = Points.Count() - 1;
        bool IsMatch = false;

        for( ; I < Points.Count(); J = I++ )
        {
            //When the position is right on a point, count it as a match.
            if( Points[ I ].X == Position.X && Points[ I ].Y == Position.Y )
                return true;
            if( Points[ J ].X == Position.X && Points[ J ].Y == Position.Y )
                return true;

            //When the position is on a horizontal or vertical line, count it as a match.
            if( Points[ I ].X == Points[ J ].X && Position.X == Points[ I ].X && Position.Y >= Math.Min( Points[ I ].Y, Points[ J ].Y ) && Position.Y <= Math.Max( Points[ I ].Y, Points[ J ].Y ) )
                return true;
            if( Points[ I ].Y == Points[ J ].Y && Position.Y == Points[ I ].Y && Position.X >= Math.Min( Points[ I ].X, Points[ J ].X ) && Position.X <= Math.Max( Points[ I ].X, Points[ J ].X ) )
                return true;

            if( ( ( Points[ I ].Y > Position.Y ) != ( Points[ J ].Y > Position.Y ) ) && ( Position.X < ( Points[ J ].X - Points[ I ].X ) * ( Position.Y - Points[ I ].Y ) / ( Points[ J ].Y - Points[ I ].Y ) + Points[ I ].X ) )
            {
                IsMatch = !IsMatch;
            }
        }

        return IsMatch;
    }
```

I hope this helps.
Enjoy!